# Does Android have a task scheduler?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, automation, applications

Microsoft Windows has the Task Scheduler Manager to schedule tasks based on time or other events, as far Linux has cron to the same feature, does Android have something like? Could I install cron on Android??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tasker. This is by far the best automated task scheduler available for android. It does come at a hefty price ($6.50 US), but it is well worth the price.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a rooted phone this should do the job:

[cron4phone free](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aes.cron4phonefree)

I just did a quick and dirty search for "cron" on the market, there could be possibly better apps for your needs